# Excel formula to find which of the matching rows has the latest Date, then update other rows with found value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A few requirements here. If you can imagine this sample table would be thousands of rows with varying Project Number values.

What I'm trying to do is use a formula that will do the following:

1. Find all rows with the same Project Number.
2. Of those matching rows, find which has the latest Date.
3. Grab the value of column 2 from the row with latest date.
4. Update the rows found in step 1 so that column 4 equals the value found in step 3.

Sample Table before formula

[image]

Desired outcome after formula

[image]

Comment: Match() comes to mind first thing, but looking at the combined 1 to 4 then perhaps vba. What have you tried so far? Have you looked at similar Q & A on here - there are some relevant. Just note this is not a free code writing service so you have to show effort.

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>Excel365</kbd> you can use below formula.

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER($A$2:$C$6,$A$2:$A$6=A2),3,-1),1,2)
```

[image]

For non `O365` user try below array formula.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(MAX(IF($A$2:$A$6=A2,$C$2:$C$6,"")),$C$2:$C$6,0))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you got older Excel version, you can combine SUMPRODUCT with SUMIFS

[image]

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$6;$C$2:$C$6;SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($A$2:$A$6=A2)*$C$2:$C$6));$A$2:$A$6;A2)
```

SUMPRODUCT will get the latest date of a project number. And we use project number and that max date as criterias, to sum up the latest comment.

Notice that if by any chance, you got 2 comments **on same date and same project** both comments will be summed up, and the result will be incorrect.